# incorrect reading of file after socket communication in java

Tags: java, file, sockets, fileinputstream, fileoutputstream

I have this file that I send from a server to a client through a socket. However when I try to reaad the first 159 first bytes in the client it gives a result that is smaller than when I ask the server to read the same amount in the original file, but when I print the length of what I read in both sides it is the same but one is almost 2/3 of the other! What could be the problem? I already made `replaceAll("(\\r|\\n|\\s)","")` to take off any space or tabulation but still no change.
Any suggestions?
Here is the code where I write the file:

```
 FileOutputStream writer = new   FileOutputStream("Splits.txt"); 
          String output= null;
          StringBuilder sb2 = new StringBuilder();
            for (int i =0; i < MainClass.NUM_OF_SPLITS ; i++){
                StringBuilder sb1 = new StringBuilder();
                     for (String s : MainClass.allSplits.get(i).blocks)
                    {sb2.append(s);}
                sb1.append(sb2);}
         output = sb2.toString().replaceAll("(\\r|\\n|\\s)", "");
         writer.write(output.getBytes(Charset.forName("ISO-8859-1")));   
         writer.close();
```

And here where I read the file:

```
  FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream("Splits.txt");
  InputStreamReader reader = new     InputStreamReader(fis,Charset.forName("ISO-8859-1"));

 for(int i = 0; i < splitsNum; i++) {
        char[] buf = new char[159]; //param
        int count = reader.read(buf);
        String h=String.valueOf(buf, 0, count).replaceAll("(\\r|\\n||\\s)","");

        System.out.println( h);
        }
```

Comment: Why are you assuming that the whole of the data will be read in a single call to `read`? What validation have you performed that the file itself has been transferred correctly?

Comment: I can open "manually" the file in the client in the client side and I see that it corresponds in the content to the initial one

Comment: Don't just manually open the file. Check the file size and ideally perform an MD5 hash on both files.

Comment: I checked with MD5, and they have the same checksum so the transfer is correct

Comment: Right. So at this point the source of the file is irrelevant - the question has nothing to do with sockets at all. You've still got a problem in that you're expecting `reader.read` to read the same amount on each read on both sides, and that's not always a valid expectation. Why don't you read a *line* at a time, or read the whole file?

Comment: because I need to take exactly the first 159 bytes and do some further computation over them and they should be the same as in the source file

Comment: Well then you should loop until you've read 159 characters (equivalent to bytes in ISO-8859-1). Don't just assume that a single call will do the trick.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to loop until you've read all the data you need:

```
char[] buf = new char[159];
int charsRead = 0;
while (charsRead < buf.length) {
    int count = reader.read(buf, charsRead, buf.length - charsRead);
    if (count < 0) {
        throw new EOFException();
    }
    charsRead += count;
}
// Right, now you know you've actually read 159 characters...
```

Comment: It works. Then what should I do if I want to read my file by 159 characters each time?

Comment: @rima101: Use that code each time you want to read 159 characters.

Comment: Surely you should be recommending the use of DataInputStream.readFully() instead of hand-coding?

Comment: @EJP: Well, that would read a *byte* array... this is reading characters. Of course the string could be constructed from the byte array afterwards. It's definitely another option. I think it's a bit of a shame that you have to wrap the `InputStream` in another stream though - I think it would be perfectly reasonable to have a static method which could be applied to *any* `InputStream` instead... like Guava's `ByteStreams.readFully` - that feels like a cleaner design to me.